# Generated "__rosidl_generator_py.so" files issue

Tags: ros, ros2, ros-humble

I've created a custom distribution using Yocto.
On it I tried to build "builtin_interfaces" from [source](https://github.com/ros2-gbp/rcl_interfaces-release/archive/release/humble/builtin_interfaces/1.2.1-1.tar.gz) (I use this example for reproducibility).

I'm able to run cmake and make but then I run into an issue related to "libpython". For example, if I look at the generated `libbuiltin_interfaces__rosidl_generator_py.so` using `ldd` :

```
ldd -r libbuiltin_interfaces__rosidl_generator_py.so 
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffdd95eb000)
        libbuiltin_interfaces__rosidl_typesupport_c.so => /home/root/rcl_interfaces-release-release-humble-builtin_interfaces-1.2.1-1/build/libbuiltin_interfaces__rosidl_typesupport_c.so (0x00007fee8ca6e000)
        libbuiltin_interfaces__rosidl_generator_c.so => /home/root/rcl_interfaces-release-release-humble-builtin_interfaces-1.2.1-1/build/libbuiltin_interfaces__rosidl_generator_c.so (0x00007fee8ca69000)
        librosidl_runtime_c.so => /usr/lib/librosidl_runtime_c.so (0x00007fee8ca5e000)
        librcutils.so => /usr/lib/librcutils.so (0x00007fee8ca46000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007fee8c83d000)
        librosidl_typesupport_c.so => /usr/lib/librosidl_typesupport_c.so (0x00007fee8c835000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fee8c625000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0x00007fee8c547000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fee8c52c000)
        /lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fee8ca7b000)
        librcpputils.so => /usr/lib/librcpputils.so (0x00007fee8c51d000)
undefined symbol: PyExc_RuntimeError    (./libbuiltin_interfaces__rosidl_generator_py.so)
undefined symbol: PyCapsule_Type        (./libbuiltin_interfaces__rosidl_generator_py.so)
undefined symbol: PyExc_AttributeError  (./libbuiltin_interfaces__rosidl_generator_py.so)
undefined symbol: PyObject_GetAttrString        (./libbuiltin_interfaces__rosidl_generator_py.so)
undefined symbol: PyObject_SetAttrString        (./libbuiltin_interfaces__rosidl_generator_py.so)
undefined symbol: _Py_Dealloc   (./libbuiltin_interfaces__rosidl_generator_py.so)
undefined symbol: PyErr_SetString       (./libbuiltin_interfaces__rosidl_generator_py.so)
undefined symbol: PyLong_FromLong       (./libbuiltin_interfaces__rosidl_generator_py.so)
undefined symbol: PyLong_AsLong (./libbuiltin_interfaces__rosidl_generator_py.so)
undefined symbol: PyImport_ImportModule (./libbuiltin_interfaces__rosidl_generator_py.so)
undefined symbol: PyObject_CallObject   (./libbuiltin_interfaces__rosidl_generator_py.so)
undefined symbol: PyLong_AsUnsignedLong (./libbuiltin_interfaces__rosidl_generator_py.so)
undefined symbol: PyLong_FromUnsignedLong       (./libbuiltin_interfaces__rosidl_generator_py.so)
undefined symbol: PyErr_Format  (./libbuiltin_interfaces__rosidl_generator_py.so)
undefined symbol: PyCapsule_GetPointer  (./libbuiltin_interfaces__rosidl_generator_py.so)
```

And I run into the same behavior for all the "__rosidl_generator_py.so" files even though `libpython` is on the device :

```
find / -name libpython*                              
/usr/lib/python3.10/config-3.10-x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.10.a
/usr/lib/libpython3.so
/usr/lib/libpython3.10.so.1.0
/usr/lib/libpython3.10.so
```

If I use the `LD_PRELOAD` environment variable (`export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/libpython3.so`), it solves my issue but I'm looking for a clean way to handle it.
How can I do so ?

**EDIT :** after a lot of pain, I found that using CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS is a possible solution. I'm using it this way : `CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS=$(python3-config --ldflags --embed)`. I don't know if a better solution exists but, at least, this one works. If you think about another solution, feel free to share !